# adb command to get internal storge

Tags: android, adb

adb shell dumspys meminfo, vmstat commands gives the RAM size available on the device. Also, I have used adb shell df, which provides available memory in different partitions of the device.  The problem with 'df' is that it provides different partitions and values on different versions.
Is there any command in adb/linux which display the free internal or sdcard memory of the device?

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `adb shell df /data`.
[image]
You can also use `adb shell df /system` for system occupied storage.